# Migrating Table Macros to VBA with a now split Database

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

What i have is the Issues template from microsoft which is all i really need for its purpose. I have converted it so that is now no longer a web database by exporting objects as client objects.

I want to split this database so that not only multiple users can utilise it at the same time but also so it performs better.

When i split the database the macros linked to the tables go to the backend so when the front end needs to use them it errors. 
 Below is and example of the add comments macro that gets called when the add comment button is pressed on the front end.

[image: Comments Macro]

And this is the macro embedded to the button
[image: Front End]

Can these be converted to VBA and interact with the backend the way it is meant to and if so where would i start. I have looked for an answer but all i find is people saying "it is fine now i have gone vba route" or similar but not actually showing it working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the converted data macro to VBA. It isn't 100% there yet as I have hard-coded the userID but this will be fixed later today, but I hope it gives a good understanding of how to convert data macros to VBA because this was a learning experience for me.

```
Private Sub cmdAddaComment_Click()

    Dim db As dao.Database, theComments As Recordset
    Set db = DBEngine.Workspaces(0).Databases(0)
    Set theComments = db.OpenRecordset("Comments")

    theComments.MoveLast
    theComments.AddNew
    theComments!IssueID = Me.ID
    theComments!CommentDate = Now
    theComments!Comment = Me.txtAddComment
    theComments!UserID = 2
    theComments.Update

    Me.txtAddComment = ""

    DoCmd.RepaintObject acForm, "IssueDetail"

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks For the Edit Gord, I Can never use the code quotes properly

Answer (score 0):

**Before doing this, make a backup of your database. You can do that by closing down the database, then locate the .accdb file on your computer, and press Ctrl+C and Ctrl+V**

You can do your own split like this:

1. Create a new, blank database.
2. Import everything EXCEPT THE TABLES from the old database
3. In the new database, create links to the old database tables. To do that, click on External Data - Import & Link, and then click on Access. Select the Link option, then locate the old database, and select all the tables you want to link. Note that if you see any tables that are named like "MSYS", do NOT import those. Those are system tables, and Access will handle those internally.
4. Now delete everything EXCEPT THE TABLES from the old database.

Your new database is now "linked" to the old database's tables, but all Forms, Reports, etc are in the new database.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't solve the issue, because there are macros assigned to the tables in question and these can't be access from a linked table

Comment: Then you'd have to determine which of those need to be in the Backend database, and which need to be in the Frontend. You'd do the same thing, expect when you do Step #2, you would import only those Macros which are needed for Frontend Objects, and when you do Step 4, you would delete all Macros except those that are needed by the Tables.

Comment: Also, if you're using Data Macros, then there is no equivalent in VBA for that. Data Macros fire based on actions performed on the Table, like Insert or Update, and you cannot "hook" those in VBA - so you can't move those directly to VBA. Other macros, such as those which work with the Forms and Reports, can very likely be moved to VBA. Unfortunately, the only way to do that is by opening each macro in design view and clicking the "Convert Macros to Visual Basic".

Comment: I have now got a solution to this after a few hours grinding i have converted them to vba i will post my answer to this tomorrow

Answer (score 0):

If you want to split an Access DB, you have to separate TABLES from all the rest.
Queries, Macros, Forms, Reports and VBA code have to stay on the frontend, and only tables on the backend.

What you are missing are the LINKS from the frontend to the backend tables.
To do that you need to create a copy of your DB, renaming it "BE.mdb" (or accdb), delete all your objects except tables from BE.mdb.
Now on the original mdb, you need to delete every table and add a link for every deleted table to the BE.mdb corresponding table. This can be done from the Import menu, choosing "link table" instead of "Import table".

Comment: This still doesnt work as the macros that are required are data macros which are not allowed with linked tables, here lies the need for VB